# ( ErrorTypeError: Failed to fetch ) Error when I try to insert values into my Mysql database ( hosted online ) from react native

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, react-native, api

Hi all I am getting an error when I try to insert values into my Mysql database ( hosted online ) from react native CLI using API .Bellow find my , Insert.js file code and test.php files .Plase help me understand as to why I am getting this error thank you in advance .

**Error->**[image]

**Insert.js code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
export default class StudentInsert extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { RollNo: "", StudentName: "", Course: "" };
  }

  InsertRecord = () => {
    var RollNo = this.state.RollNo;
    var StudentName = this.state.StudentName;
    var Course = this.state.Course;

    if (RollNo.length == 0 || StudentName.length == 0 || Course.length == 0) {
      alert("Please complete all the fields");
    } else {
      var InsertAPIURL = 'https://app.wakilicloud.co.ke/config.php';
      var headers2 = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      };
      var Data = {
        RollNo: 'RollNo',
        StudentName: 'StudentName',
        Course: 'Course'
      };
      fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers2,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          alert(response[0].Message);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert("Error" + error);
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={"RollNo"}
          placeholderTextColor={"pink"}
          keyboardType={"number"}
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          onChangeText={(RollNo) => this.setState({ RollNo })}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder={"Student Name"}
          placeholderTextColor={"pink"}
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          onChangeText={(StudentName) => this.setState({ StudentName })}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder={"Course"}
          placeholderTextColor={"pink"}
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          onChangeText={(Course) => this.setState({ Course })}
        />

        <Button title={"Save"} onPress={this.InsertRecord} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 10
  },
  txtStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "red",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
});
```

**test.php**

[image]

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using http request. React native needs https connection to send request. You can switch your server into https, or [read this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24408) for continue using http request (deprecated)
2. Your request's body is reduntdant a comma, try to remove it before send request.

```
var Data = {
    RollNo: 'RollNo',
    StudentName: 'StudentName',
    Course: 'Course', // => remove it
};
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response , I have done the edits and updated the code above but I am still getting the same error  . Do you think the problem could be with the test.php file ? .